# How to access other table field through foreign key in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm stuck on something. How can I access the `userroleid` from my `validatorid` foreign key? I'm trying to do validation on serializer level. I tried something like `data['validatorid__userroleid']` but it raises an error.
Hope someone can help me on this!

Here's my serializers

```
class ValidatorPartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = partsTable
        fields = ['pid', 'partsid', 'validatorid', (...)]
        read_only_fields = ['pid', 'partsid',(...)]
​
    def validate(self, data):
        if data['validatorid'] != 2: #how can I access userroleid from here?
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Sorry! You entered a user with no validator permissions.")
        return data
​
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.validatorid = validated_data.get('validatorid', instance.validatorid)
        instance.partsstatusid = validated_data.get('partsstatusid', instance.partsstatusid)
        instance.save()            
        return instance
```

Here's my model for reference:

```
class partsTable(models.Model):
​
    pid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    partsid = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True)
    validatorid = models.ForeignKey(userTable, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    (...)
​
class userTable(models.Model):
    userid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default = uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, unique=True)
    userroleid = models.ForeignKey(roleTable, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
​
class roleTable(models.Model):
    roleid = models.IntegerField(null=False, primary_key=True)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rename the foreign key fields, maybe it will help to understand how Django works:
validatorid >> validator || userroleid >> user_role

Then inside your code you can do:

```
class ValidatorPartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = partsTable
        fields = ['pid', 'partsid', 'validator', (...)]
        read_only_fields = ['pid', 'partsid',(...)]
​
    def validate(self, data):
        try:
          user = userTable.objects.get(validator_id=data['validator'])
        except userTable.DoesNotExist:
          raise serializers.ValidationError("No user exists for this validator_id")
        if user.user_role.role_id != 2:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Sorry! You entered a user with no validator permissions.")
        return data
```

So, what you see here is that I suggest you get the User from the db, then access the role id through it's relationship